# Find lowest value in a hash

Tags: ruby

```
a = { 
      1 => ["walmart", "walmart.com", 300.0], 
      2 => ["amazon", "amazon.com", 350.0], 
      ...
    }
```

How do I find the element with lowest value of the float value in its array?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

See the `min_by` solution in the answer below. My original answer to this question was way less efficient, as pointed out in the comment.

Comment: -1. This is the wrong algorithm in general as it's `O(N log(N))` when there is a `O(N)` solution.

Answer (score 31):

[`min_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-min_by) is available as a method from the `Enumerable` module.

It gets the array of all values in the Hash, and then picks the minimum value based on the last element of each array.

```
a.values.min_by(&:last)
```

Answer (score 4):

Another useful method is [sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) from the **Enumerable** module as well. It will arrange your hash from ascending order. Then chain the method with [first](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-first) to grab the lowest value.

```
a.sort_by { |key, value| value }.first
```